# How can I avoid IndexError: list index out of range when the range can be random amount of splits, using Python 3?

Tags: python, input, split, index-error

Lets say I have a split string that can have up to x amount of words, and that split set changes randomly. (I'm using 3 in this example.) If at any time I have to retrieve the 3rd word and the 3rd word doesn't exist, how can I avoid "IndexError: list index out of range". The 3 strings wordOne, wordTwo and wordThree must exist for use later.

```
userInput = input('Type up to 3 words : ')
userInputSplit = userInput.split()

wordOne = userInputSplit[0]
if userInputSplit[1] != None:
    wordTwo = userInputSplit[1]
if userInputSplit[2] != None:
    wordThree = userInputSplit[2]


print(wordOne + ' ' + wordTwo + ' ' + wordThree)
```

Comment: Please provide what would be the expected output (value of wordOne, wordTwo, wordThree) if userInput = "a b c" and if userInput = "a b"

Comment: You said these variables "must exist for use later". Can you explain why you think you need separate variables, one for each word? What exactly do you intend to do with those variables, besides printing them? I suspect that, whatever it is you're trying to do, there exists an easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of the `userInputSplit`:

```
userInput = input('Type up to 3 words : ')
userInputSplit = userInput.split()

wordOne = userInputSplit[0]
if len(userInputSplit) == 1:
    wordTwo = 'None'
    wordThree = 'None'
elif len(userInputSplit) == 2:
    wordTwo = userInputSplit[1]      
    wordThree = 'None'
else:
    wordTwo = userInputSplit[1]      
    wordThree = userInputSplit[2]
```

The above code can be written in 2 lines:

```
wordTwo = userInputSplit[1] if len(userInputSplit])>1 else 'None'
wordThree = userInputSplit[2] if len(userInputSplit])>2 else 'None'
```

You can also use try-except:

```
try:
    wordTwo = userInputSplit[1]
except IndexError: 
    wordTwo = 'None'
try:
    wordThree = userInputSplit[2]
except IndexError: 
    wordThree = 'None'
```